# Colour bleeds right when writing a custom script in byobu

Tags: colors, tmux, byobu

I am using byobu with tmux backend in Ubuntu 12.04.

I am trying write a custom script as shown at the manpage of byobu:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "\005{= bw}%s\005{-}" "$(uname -r)"
```

When being run (using an arbitrary interval, e.g 10 seconds), it does not show anything, but bleeds the white colour to the right. By replacing `printf` with `echo`, bleeding stops, but the message appeared, is showing the `{-}` after the command.
I can't figure out how to solve it!

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The bug is in version 5.21 of byobu currently on the official Ubuntu repos. In the byobu PPA, version 5.22 doesn't bleed colors to the right anymore. Still no answer on the `{-}` issue.

Procedure:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:byobu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install byobu
```